# Tasks and events custom related list

Tags: apex, related-list

Is it possible to create a custom related list for the mentioned objects? From what I've read you have to create a custom object with a master-detail or lookup relationship, I've been able to accomplish this for other objects like accounts, contacts and opportunities but tasks and events are not available on the picklist. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the "Allow Activities" (Track Activities) checkbox in the Custom Object Definition to view tasks and events in a custom related list. To do this:

1. Click Your `Name | Setup | Create | Objects`.
2. Click Edit to modify an existing custom object.
3. Check the "`Allow Activities"` checkbox under `Optional Features`.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested in pursuing this further, I put in a request in the idea exchange (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DqTVAA0).

Answer (score 0):

That's not quite what I want to achieve. I wish to create a custom related list that would be visible in tasks and activities. When I try to create a lookup relationship in my created object (Allow activities is checked) I can't see either tasks nor events on the list.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding another answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom VF Page for the object you are interested in, insert a `<apex:detail>` tag to display standard page for the object, and create your custom related list on your own, with `<apex:pageBlockTable>`. This is the way to create a fully customized lists, e.g. with some custom sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Activities (Tasks and Events) cannot be the type of a lookup field for any object.

Out of the box an activity can only link to a single 'What' object, and can be linked to a maximum of 50 'Who' (Contact) objects if it's non-recurring and the feature has been enabled.

You would need to create a custom Visualforce page extending the relevant standard controller and build your related list completely using custom code to achieve what I think you want.